# USB 3 hard drive and card not working in super-speed mode

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb

So, I recently added a USB3 card to my computer, and I thought everything was good, Linux detected it, though weirdly (or not?) it comes up as 2 hubs

```
[    2.086988] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.086996] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    2.092364] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: hcc params 0x014051cf hci version 0x100 quirks 0x00000010
[    2.092561] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    2.092563] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.092564] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.092565] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 xhci-hcd
[    2.092566] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:07:00.0
```

and

```
[    2.092881] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.092884] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    2.092921] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: debug port 1
[    2.095951] usb usb3: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[    2.095965] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    2.095966] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.095967] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.095968] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 xhci-hcd
[    2.095969] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:07:00.0
[    2.096100] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.096116] hub 3-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
```

this is similary seen with lsusb, where it shows both devices being handled by xhci

```
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 480M
```

and hence the problem, my USB3 hard drive, which reports supporting superspeed is only connecting to the usb2 (highspeed?) hub.

this is shown in dmesg as well

when attached, I see

```
[538663.101097] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[538663.246919] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab44
[538663.246922] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[538663.246923] usb 2-4: Product: Backup+ Hub
[538663.246924] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Seagate
[538663.246925] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 01CB7196B0S3
[538663.248429] hub 2-4:1.0: USB hub found
[538663.248973] hub 2-4:1.0: 3 ports detected
[538664.169034] usb 2-4.1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[538664.319996] usb 2-4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab38
[538664.319999] usb 2-4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[538664.320000] usb 2-4.1: Product: Backup+ Hub BK
[538664.320001] usb 2-4.1: Manufacturer: Seagate
```

lsusb -v for the external hard drive shows that it does support super-speed

```
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
```

so I'm at a loss in how to proceed.  Is my card defective?  Is Linux doing something wrong?  Anyway to force it to use the other "hub"?

Comment: Are you sure that your HDD is working in SS mode and not broken?

Comment: And what is your "a USB3 card", does it have a name? The VID/PID for host controller look like some bootleg product assigned to Linux. What is the actual hardware on the card?

Comment: this guy http://www.ebay.com/itm/162547364299 and I do expect it could be a hardware issue, hence my Q about how it reports 2 hubs.  

The drive is reporting its SS capable, and Linux is just putting it on the 480M "hub".  Its doesn't seem like it trying it on superspeed and failing (But maybe it is and the logging just isnt verbose enough).  I'm going to try it on a different windows box I have, but I do expect it to work there (I've attached 5 drives to it, and I've never had an issue with these seagate drives working at SS, but none work here)

Comment: Yes, you try it under Windos, excellent idea. The chip is a reputable Renesas/NEC, but the new one, 4-port, uPD720201. The system reports two hubs because there are logically two hubs, USB3, and USB2. But the manufacturer might be a suspect, and signal integrity might be a suspect. Or your linux driver nor ready to support 4-port USB3.

Comment: I will say, it looks really well made, solid overall, but looks aren't everything I guess.  a driver issue could be it, as I'd expect bad manufacturing to result in errors.  I've reported it to the linux-usb list, will see if they say anything.

Comment: Did you try some simple USB3 flash drives, to exclude possible cable issues? USB3 connection should start first, and if LFPS handshake/link training fails, then it should fall back into USB2 mode. If signal integrity is in question, the SS link should succeed time to time. But it looks like your card never tried to connect at SS speed, although all this is at hardware level, and is invisible for software. You should try this device, http://www.kage-electronics.com/PRODUCTS.php to see if any SS attempt was made or not.

Comment: I was requested to post a debug log to the linux-usb list, so waiting for them to digest that.  they seem to think it might be a driver issue.

Comment: and you were right about the chip, didn't think to do an lspci -nn, it shows 07:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720201 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1912:0014] (rev 03)